# Unable to edit array inside of function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to add (`push`) an element to a global array inside of a function with no luck. The function is called by an `addEventListener()` if that's at all helpful.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
function addInfo(){
    cars.push(document.getElementById("new_car").value);
}

//add listener
document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0].addEventListener("click", addInfo());
```

This is resulting in the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How can I store all newly submitted items to keep a running tally?

Comment: On the last line, remove change `addInfo()` to `addInfo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**`addEventListener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) expects second argument(`listener`) as `function-expression`,

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

function addInfo() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("new_car");
  cars.push(elem.value);
  elem.value = '';
  elem.focus();
  console.log(cars);
}
document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0].addEventListener("click", addInfo);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="new_car" autofocus>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Add" class="add">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, although it's allowing me to actually access the array now with addInfo() I am unable to modify the array with this implementation

Comment: Form some reason, if you add this into a form and have two different buttons, it never saves the state of the list: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2fbff074a5458e75ec2981d0b16692e5

Comment: You are missing `type='button'` and that is the reason it treats the button as `submit` button... [Fiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/t9wocxvb/)